# What are "spheres" in Neal Stephenson's "Anathem?"

Tags: anathem

In "Anathem," the avout (fraa and suur) used "spheres" to do various things.  The spheres wered used as a tool to make life comfortable in most cases, but what are they exactly?  How should I visualize them?  Stephenson didn't really paint a clear picture of it.

[**Amazon link to Anathem**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061474096)

[**Google Books preview of Anathem**](http://books.google.com/books?id=CgeHW-geducC&printsec=frontcover&dq=anathem&hl=en&src=bmrr&ei=ibuvTvW-MMTk0QHrrojnAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: It is also made of "newmatter", just like a cord, which is why it has all these strange properties. These are the only pieces of advanced technology allowed in the mathic world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is hard to describe a visual image of the spheres, simply because their forms were so malleable.

> The sphere is a porous membrane.  Each pore is a little pump that can
>   move air in or out.  Like a self-inflating balloon.  The spring
>   constant - the stretchiness - of the membrane is controllable.  If you
>   turn the stretchiness way down (that is, make it stiff) and pump in
>   lots of air, becomes a hard little pill.

You can also do the opposite, and make the membrane very stretchy, and or/remove most of the air.

So the sphere can look like anything from a small, hard ball, to a large, floppy disk, plus anything in between (in the passage that follows the above quote, fraa Erasmas makes his sphere into a flat mat, and then inflates it into an air bed between two and three feet in diameter).

In another reference, it can be shrunk to a size that fits easily in the palm of a hand.

Comment: I guess that'll do, even though those are the ideas I had anyway.  Like you said, it's hard to describe a visual image.  Thanks.

Comment: In addition to the above mentioned features, the spheres could also be made to glow, to be used as low level lighting.

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing is a geometric metaphor. Think about it: you have the "bolt" which is a flat sheet, basically a cartesian plane. Then you have the "chord", which is a rope, or a platonic line, and then you have the "sphere", which is a sphere.

It has some practical applications (as you see in the book), but it's mainly symbolic.